# What is alternative for HasForeignKey and ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo method in ef core3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

In a project with .net core 2.2 and ef core 2.2 I had below codes In my dbContext to set one to many relationship between Reference Entity and it,s workdowns in **OnModelCreating** method of dbContext:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>().OwnsMany<WorkDown>("WorkDowns", a =>
        {
            a.HasForeignKey("ReferenceId");
            a.Property(ca => ca.Action).IsRequired();
            a.Property(ca => ca.Note);
            a.Property(ca => ca.WorkDownId).ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo("WorkDownSequence");
            a.HasKey("WorkDownId");
        });
```

It works perfectly in that project wit .netcor 2.2, but in another project that I use .net core and ef core 3 I could not find any alternativ for **HasForeignKey** and **ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo** extension methods is there any substitue method or any alternative way in efcore 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the 3.0 breaking changes - [Configuration API for owned type relationships has changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#configuration-api-for-owned-type-relationships-has-changed):

> The configuration related to the relationship between owner and owned should now be chained after `WithOwner()` similarly to how other relationships are configured. While the configuration for the owned type itself would still be chained after `OwnsOne()/OwnsMany()`.

i.e. you need to use one of the `WithOwner` overloads in order to get access to relationship configuration methods like `HasForeignKey` / `HasPrincipalKey`, e.g.

```
a.WithOwner()
    .HasForeignKey("ReferenceId");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works perfectly , but do you know any substitue for ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo?

Comment: You are welcome. In general, if `ForAbcXyz` method disappers, look for (common) `Xyz` method. In this case it's not exactly the same pattern, but the new common method is `UseHiLo`.